# ¿Cómo aplicar permisos a todas las bases de datos en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Estoy asignando permisos en PostgreSQL, Tengo el comando:

```
grant all privileges on database db1,db2,db3 to usuario;
```

Sin embargo si tengo muchas bases de datos tendría que escribir una por una, ¿existe alguna forma de aplicar los privilegios a todas las bases de datos?

Comment: He estado buscando información y aun no consigo nada al respecto, ¿No has intentado colocar database all?

Comment: No lo he intentado, probaré a ver que pasa.